# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have sometimes this error

> The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a
>   notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
>   from a background thread

But i don't understand because i run to UI thread. If you have an idea, thks.

```
class LoadingProducts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading_indicator.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (isAdded()) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    mAdapter.setData(listProducts);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    loading_indicator.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        get_data();
        return null;
    }
}
```

UPDATED :
This problem appear on refreshing list by search

previous code onQueryTextChange :

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

           if (mQueryStringSearch.length() > 2)
               new LoadingProducts().execute();


        }
    }, 300);
```

Comment: To make this question more clear, please add a specific condition under which you get this error. E.g. what causes this error to occur? What are the steps you take before this error occurs? Does your program compile? These things will help others solve your problem more accurately.

Comment: data coming from sqlite database, i'm searching data on query. You suggested i load all data and filter after? there can be big data to filter.

Comment: yes but i don't load data in listview before my search. this is not a search in listview, only results.

Comment: no, my listview show only results if user searching

Comment: I use a BaseAdapter because my cursor is transformed to a object and already filtered before this search. It's a complex query with many data.